# Strawberry perl: need to use ampersand in a backtick command as a parameter, not as background

Tags: escaping, ampersand, strawberry-perl, backticks

I am trying to get a "wget" post command to run from a perl script.  I'm using strawberry perl on a Windows 7 machine.  The post parameter includes ampersand (&) characters and when I run the wget inside of a backtick, the ampersand is treated like the end of the command as a if I am wanting everything before the ampersand to run in the background.  I've tried several ways to attempt to properly escape the ampersand.  But, I've run out of ideas.

So, the command I'm trying to run is something like:

```
$wget = "/c/workarea/wget/bin/wget";
$value1 = 1;
$groupName = "group1";
$output = `$wget --post-data 'Field1=${value1}&Field2=Val2&Field3=${groupName}' "http://localhost/LocalPage"`;
```

If I run the command from a bash command line, like the following it works fine:

```
/c/workarea/wget/bin/wget --post-data 'Field1=1&Field2=Val2&Field3=group1' "http://localhost/LocalPage"
```

But, when I run it inside the perl script I get errors like the following:

'Field2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

'Field3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I've put the full "post" part of the command that is in single quotes inside of double quotes because I found that as a suggestion that indicated that anything inside of the double quotes doesn't get interpreted.  That seemed to work in term of the command being executed not treating the '&' as a "run in the background" character.  But, the resulting command being executed isn't doing what I want it to do.  Meaning the POST isn't posting from the perl script like it does when I run the command like above from the command line.  I've tried to escape the '&' character using a single '\', and a double '\', since I know that sometimes there can be a need for the escape to occur multiple times as the string is being passed along.  I even tried it with '\\'.  But, that didn't seem to have any affect.

I'd like to use the backtick so I can parse the output of the command for further decision making later in the script.  So, I think I need the backtick instead of 'system()'.

Thanks in advance for any help on how I need to escape or quote this to get the proper handling.  Or, if there is a way to see what is being attempted inside the backtick after it's been interpreted and passed to the shell to be executed.  If I knew that, I think I might be able to tell better what I'm doing wrong.

Regards,
sjmyst

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out how to figure it out by writing a script to output the parameters.  So, what I did was write the following script and named it test.pl:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env perl.exe

 print "ENTERING test.pl...\n";

 $i = 0;
 foreach my $arg (@ARGV) {
   print "i = $i\n";
   print "ARGV[$i] = $ARGV[$i]\n";
   $i = $i + 1;
 }
```

Then, instead of calling 'wget' with the parameters like above, I called test.pl passing in the parameters I had been passing to 'wget'.  I was then able to see what 'wget' would see after the shell from the backtick interpreted the POST arguments and passed them to 'wget'.  I probably should have figured that out before posting.  Hopefully this might help a newbie like me to figure these escaping issues.  So, something like this:

```
 $wget = "/c/workarea/wget/bin/wget";
 $value1 = 1;
 $groupName = "group1";
 # Wasn't working
 #$output = `$wget --post-data 'Field1=${value1}&Field2=Val2&Field3=${groupName}' "http://localhost/LocalPage"`;
 # Eventually got working by seeing what was passed into test.pl
 $output = `test.pl --post-data "Field1=${value1}&Field2=Val2&Field3=${groupName}" \"http://localhost/LocalPage\"`;
```

The bottom line was that I needed ONLY double quotes around the POST parameters.  So, I only included the double quotes and removed the single quotes altogether.  This passed the string to the 'wget' as is, as one parameter without the backtick shell treating the '&' as a "run in the background" character.

Regards,

sjmyst